# Vue - unable to access component functions/data within handler method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a function in Vue called doSomething() and a event handler within it called onmessage() that is also it's own function. However within onmessage I cannot access anything within the component. I cannot access the components variables or methods.

How can I gain access to the components data from within that function?

```
export default {
  name: "component",
  data() {
    return {
      name: "Jeb",
      connection: null
      }
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething: function() {
      
      this.connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2000");
      this.connection.onmessage = function(event) {
       
         console.log(this.name); //UNDEFINED
         this.doAnotherThing(); //ERROR 
      };
      ...
      ...
    },
    doAnotherThing: function() {
      ...
    }
  }
};
```

I apologize in advance if this question has been asked before. I have tried searching for it for some time but couldn't find a similar post.

Comment: Try using an arrow function instead.  If you `console.log(this)` I assume it would log the `this.connection` variable, since that is what the event handler is being put on

Answer (score 0):

Change way how you organize the code of methods:

```
doSomething() {
  this.connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2000");
  ...
```